# How to redirect to Activity A on oauth success or Activity B on oauth failed

Tags: android

I have three activities A, B and C. When a button is clicked in activity C it opens a browser intent which the user can approve or deny the request. When the user approves the request I want to redirect back to the app and opens activity A but if the user denies the request I want to also redirect to the app but to activity B.

I've successfully managed to redirect back to the app but I can't figure out how to redirect to either A or B.

In the api documentation [here](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/authentication/how-do-i-generate-a-session-id), it says when the user clicks approve, they will be redirected to custom url if specified, but it doesn't say anything about if the user denies the request.

Here's my code

```
token = response.getString("request_token");

                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.themoviedb.org/authenticate/" + token + "?redirect_to=schemeName://hostName/path"));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity" android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"
        android:configChanges="orientation" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:host="hostname"
            android:path="/path"
            android:scheme="schemename" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a common activity other than A & B, redirect to that activity from the browser and also send the flag for "allow" or "deny". After returning to the common activity check with that flag value and navigate to the corresponding activity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm fairly new to Android, can you please provide a code sample or a link explaining this. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can start the authentication activity for result. That way you can pass data from the first activity to the second one and depending on the result you can return them to the correct activity.

In Activity C:

```
startActivityForResult(browserIntent, a_unique_integer_code);
```

in the Browser Activity:

```
    //if authentication succeeds
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();       
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
    //else:
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent(); 
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
        finish();
```

and in your Activity C accept the result and according to what you get start the desired activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == a_unique_integer_code) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            //start activity a
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
           //start activity b
        }
    }
}
```